# How do the vacuum bubbles cancel out in gell-mann-low formular?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, perturbation-theory

In interacting quantum field theory we often want to calculate vacuum expectation values of the interacting theory using the gell-mann-low formular. Lets consider two interacting real scalar fields in $\phi^3$-theory up to order of $\lambda^2$.
\begin{align}
<\Omega|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|\Omega>= \frac{<0|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\exp(i\int d^4z\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3(z))\}|0>}{<0|T\{\exp(i\int d^4z\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3(z))\}|0>}
\end{align}
We can then calculate this vacuum expectation values of the free theory using Wick's theorem.
Lets first have a look at the numerator:
We get 6 different terms, each of which can be expressed as a feynman-diagram. Two of this diagrams contain "vacuum bubbles", that are connected subgraphs, that do not contain an external point.
Now lets have a look at the denominator:
Here we get only two non vanishing terms, which are exatly these vacuum bubbles. In the literature I can find, that these vacuum bubbles in the numerator can always be factored out and therefore cancel with the denominator. But I can not see why this is the case, because what we have is something like
\begin{align}
<\Omega|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|\Omega>= \frac{\sum_{\textit{connected}}+\sum_{\textit{containing bubbles}}}{1+\sum_{\textit{bubbles}}}
\end{align}
I see, that a single diagram, that contains one such bubble can be factored in a part containing just the bubble, and one part containing the other connected part, that contains the external points. But I can not see how the bubbles actually cancel out in the formular above, since only two of the 6 diagrams in the numerator contain these bubbles.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51993/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365537/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606672/226902